# Parsing error in Google spreadsheet for ImportHTML

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, html-parsing

I am trying to the 5th table (Shareholders) from the website but there was a parsing error.
Could anyone advice how to solve it?

My code:

```
=ImportHTML(“https://www.marketscreener.com/YANGZIJIANG-SHIPBUILDING-6499571/company/”, “table”, 5)
```

Comment: you have smart quotes (usually from copy pasting) instead of normal quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is something wrong with the quotation marks you used. Please try

```
=ImportHTML("https://www.marketscreener.com/YANGZIJIANG-SHIPBUILDING-6499571/company/", "table", 5)
```

and see if that helps?

Answer (score -1):

Resolve parsing error by using ';'s instead of ','s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).